# TabControl.ItemTemplate Not Completely Filling Tab Header Background

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set the background color of a tab header but it is not filling the entire header, but leaving a margin around my template. I need to get it to completely fill the tab's header with the background color.

Here is some trivial code that demonstrates the behavior:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="TabControl">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="BlueViolet">
                        <TextBlock Height="20" Width="60" Text="TEST"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TabControl.Items.Add(new Grid());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably have to replace the control template of the `TabControl` with something that displays the tabs differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to strip out the `TabItem` control template if you want the `Background` to be filled.

The original control template of a `TabItem` looks like this,

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Grid>
      <Border 
        Name="Border"
        Margin="0,0,-4,0" 
        Background="{StaticResource LightBrush}"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
        CornerRadius="2,12,0,0" >
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          ContentSource="Header"
          Margin="12,2,12,2"
          RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
      </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

As you can see inside the `Template` it has a `Border` and its child is a `ContentPresenter` which is basically what you modified in your `ItemTemplate` for the `TabControl` it doesn't fill out because the `Border` has its own background color which you can see it defined as `LightBrush`. In order to change this behavior you have to customize your `TabItem` template something like this.

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border 
                                    Name="Border"
                                    Margin="0,0,-4,0" 
                                    Background="BlueViolet"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                                    CornerRadius="2,12,0,0" >
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                      Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="BlueViolet" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Height="20" Width="60" Text="TEST"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Notice I explicitly changed the `Background` to `BlueViolet`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to set Padding to a small value and add a margin to a TextBlock:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Orange">
                        <ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Content>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```